# Multiple Commands Produce *.Framework

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, podspec

I am working on a making a library **MyLibrary** for one on my **Project**. Once the library has been completed I have to add **MyLibrary** as a private pod project using GitHub link into my **Project**. Now I am having some issues when I try to integrate my library using pod file.

My **Project** has other Development Pods integrated in it using pod file. Those development pods has their own dependencies on 3rd party library like Alamofire or Hero etc. And my library also has 3rd party dependencies like Alamofire and Hero etc.

I have included **MyLibrary** pod dependencies in my podspec file like below:

```
spec.dependency "Hero"
spec.dependency "Alamofire"
```

Now when I integrate **MyLibraray** into my project it gives the following error on my project and I am not sure how to resolve that, and this error is coming for all the libraries which are same with other development pods.

Showing Recent Messages

```
Multiple commands produce '[Path To Simulator]/APPNAME.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework':
1) That command depends on command in Target 'APPNAME' (project 'APPNAME'): script phase “[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks”
2) That command depends on command in Target 'APPNAME' (project 'APPNAME'): script phase “[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks”
```

I am new to these pod stuff, but can you guys please help in this thing.

Comment: Let's cut through this Pod stuff - it may be noise. And yes, your question *might* make sense but is *clearly* no enough for me to duplicate. So is the issue the **Project A** uses **Framework A** and *FrameworkB** - but yet those frameworks **BOTH** use **FrameworkC**?

Comment: @dfd, Yes actually that's correct.